# How to pass array value from code behind to jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am using jQuery in my web application. There are two fields where I want to pass an array value from code behind using jQuery.

I am using this code for a graph:

```
var chart2={
  label:names['c2'],
  type:$('select[@name=c2type]').val(),
  color:$('select[@name=c2color]').val(),
  values:getTableCol('c2'),
  stackedOn:names[$('select[@name=c2stack]').val()]};
```

In `values:getTableCol('c2')` I need to pass the array value from a code behind page. Right now it's taking its value from a table column but I don't need the table. Here I want to pass a value of form `{12,45,45,50,55}` at run time. It is changeable.

How can I pass this value?

Answer (score 1):

You could serialize to JSON and put in the page - JSON is legal JavaScript.

Code-behind:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

protected string JsonArray
{
  get {
    var myArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myArray);
  }
}
```

.aspx:

```
var chart2 = {
  values: <%= JsonArray %>
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the following inside Page_PreRender:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "DeclareMyArray", @"var myArray = ['hello', 'world'];", true);
```

Then you should be able to do the following:

```
var chart2={
   label:names['c2'],
   type:$('select[@name=c2type]').val(),
   color:$('select[@name=c2color]').val(),
   values:myArray,
   stackedOn:names[$('select[@name=c2stack]').val()]};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could render the value into a hidden field on the page using the [HtmlInputHidden](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/control_htmlinputhidden.asp) control. Provided you give the field an ID that can be referenced from jQuery you will be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// selects both table header and table data cells from the third column of #mytable
$('#mytable th:nth-col(3), #mytable td:nth-col(3)');

// same as above but using the nthCol extension function
$('#mytable th, #mytable td).nthCol(3);
```

copied from http://www.bramstein.com/projects/column/